# Undefined reference to HMAC APIs during compilation

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I have attached a code snippet below which is creating a Message Authenticated Code (MAC) using OpenSSL v1.0.2u HMAC APIs. I having trouble compiling the code.

```
int main() {
        // The secret key for hashing
        const char key[] = "012345678";
        // The data that we're going to hash
        char data[] = "hello world";
        // Be careful of the length of string with the choosen hash engine. SHA1 needed 20 characters.
        // Change the length accordingly with your choosen hash engine.
        unsigned char* result;
        unsigned int len = 20;
        result = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
        HMAC_CTX *ctx;
        //ctx = HMAC_CTX_new();
        HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
        // Using sha1 hash engine here.
        // You may use other hash engines. e.g EVP_md5(), EVP_sha224, EVP_sha512, etc
        HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, strlen(key), EVP_sha1(), NULL);
        HMAC_Update(&ctx, (unsigned char*)&data, strlen(data));
        HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &len);
        HMAC_CTX_free(&ctx);
        printf("HMAC digest: ");
        for (int i = 0; i != len; i++)
                printf("%02x", (unsigned int)result[i]);
        printf("\n");
        free(result);
        return 0;
}
```

Command used for compiling:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include, main.c -Wl,-L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Output: Compilation failed with the following error:

```
main.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: Could you provide the full code, or at least references to your "#include" directives?

Comment: Can you try to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as `/usr/local/ssl/lib/` and compile again?

Comment: Did you `#include <openssl/hmac.h>`?

Comment: Like the question as I'm having a similar issue compiling a product that uses openssl 1.0.2u.  However I don't see an answer or comment that hints at a solution.  @kusai did you ever figure it out on your own?  If so could you answer your own question?